# How can i require an entry point in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, entry-point

Im trying to export these two pieces of code cli.js and program.js, where cli depends on program and program has a bunch of other dependencies...

Webpack is doing a great job in bundling all dependencies of program.js (./a,./b,./c...) and correctly ignoring the ones that are externals like 'jquery', 'bluebird' ...

however when it comes to bundle the cli.js .. its not referencing the **program.dist.js** entry point, but bundling a copy of the entire program once again...

**how could i fix this issue? is it a limitation with webpack? or is there any way around it? im currently using webpack 2.1.0-beta.27**

this is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        cli: './bin/cli.js',
        program: './program.js',
    },
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        filename: '[name].dist.js',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'distribution'),
    },
    externals: [
        /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/
    ]
}
```

**program.js**

```
let a = require('./a'),
    b = require('./b'),
    c = require('./c');
```

**bin/cli.js**

```
const program = require('../program');
      program.doSomething();
```

just a side node...

I cant split it into chunks with CommonsChunkPlugin because it would make my cli.dist.js unable to be executed by node.js like `node cli.dist.js`